# Predicting WorldPay transaction ID with Shopify

Tags: shopify, worldpay

We're using the WorldPay payment processor with Shopify.

When a transaction is created in WorldPay it's given an ID based on its order number in Shopify. For example:

- #1010.1 for order number 1010
- #1011.1 for order number 1011
- #1013.2 for order number 1013

For most orders the number after the dot is a "1". But for at least one it's "2". Is there any way of predicting what this number is, or of fetching it via the API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part after the #1013 is the transaction number. If the transaction fails for whatever reason that number is incremented when the user attempts the transaction again. You can retrieve the transactions for an order using the transactions endpoint. http://api.shopify.com/transactions.html